# How many mails can I send with google app engine per day?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I found that:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail

But I do not really see how much mails can be send using the JAVA Api?

so 5000 mails with 100 recipients?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An unbilled user:**

- Can email up to 100 non-admin recipients per day.
- Can email up to 5000 admin recipients per day.

In other words: 100 emails per day to one non-admin recipient or one email per day to 100 recipients plus 5000 emails per day to one admin recipient.

**A billed user:**

- Can email 100 non-admin recipients until first charge cleared; then
  100 non-admin recipients for free and no maximum thereafter.
- Can email 3 000 000 admin recipients

Comment: Those are only the limits without billing enabled. If you enable billing, after your first bill, there are no practical limits other than cost, as long as you're not abusive.

Comment: @NickJohnson I assumed, given the explicit reference to 5000 and 100, that the OP was referring to the free option. I've updated my answer in response to your comments - thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to use Amazon SES for the mail service, because you do not receive any delivery feeback from the GAE mail service. "Amazon SES provides a built-in feedback loop, which includes notifications of bounce backs, failed and successful delivery attempts, and spam complaints."

Comment: How much mails can i send with SES?

Comment: Email messages are charged at $0.10 per thousand. See details: http://aws.amazon.com/ses/#pricing. By the way. I'am a great fan of GAE and it services. Except for the mail service.